# Using #ifdef in classes declaration to make implementation available only during debug for unit testing purposes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm starting with unit testing and I want to write tests to some classes that already have an implementation.

We are developing for interfaces in this project and I guess it helps when writing unit testing.
But the interfaces implementations are marked as **internal** and the best solution I've found until now to test the implementation is this:

```
#if DEBUG
public class CreateRequestService : DomainServiceBase, ICreateRequestService
#else
internal class CreateRequestService : DomainServiceBase, ICreateRequestService
#endif
{
```

What do you think of that? I was trying to figure out how to use autofac in the unit tests but it smelled a lot to me. Is it a good practice?

## Update

I forgot to specify the tools I'm using. I'm using C# 4.5, NUnit and Moq!

Comment: What language you are using ?

Comment: I'm using C# 4.5, NUnit and Moq! Sorry about that!

Comment: I would advise that you do not do the #if DEBUG thing. First it is very invasive and you can have a lot of those lines in your code base. And even more important: you are testing different code then will be used in production.

Comment: I'm not testing different code. Actually is the same code that goes to production, I just need to call new Class() from the test and inject it's dependencies. I'm new to this unit test thing and I guess I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Someone can in 2 years add #if DEBUG a++ #else b++ #endif. You will not be able to catch that bug as you can only unittest the DEBUG code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to hide classes and interfaces like that some years ago. Stopped doing that, would use it only if I was developing libraries.

If you are using .NET you can make "friend assemblies". That way unit testing assembly can see internal  members of production assembly. But for that you need to have access to code in production assembly (you need to add an assembly attribute).

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Another option is simply to make classes and interfaces public and move them to

```
 MyProduct.xxx.yyy.Internal
```

namespace. That way you can test and every member of the team knows that it shouldn't use those members.

Comment: Hi Petar! Thanks for your help! I did change the implementations to internal (they used to be public and are in the same assembly as the interfaces) just to speed up the concept of IoC and DI. Doing so, the other members can't just call new Class() from outside the allowed scope!